# Highcharts tooltip date format when using pointFormat

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, datetime-format

hi i am working on highcharts with net transactions on y-axis and type datetime on x-axis. i have shown month and date on x-axis point label as (jan 2016) and want to show the same date format on tooltip. but its showing full date with day as well like "Monday, jan 1, 2016.

here is my js code.

```
tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.x:%Y-%m}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0;font-size:11px;">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:,.0f}</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Add your data response json

Comment: You can use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and customise content and dates (by [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat))

Answer (score 7):

Just change your point.X: format string **from** `{point.x:%Y-%m}` **to** `{point.x:%b-%Y}` as shown bellow

```
tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.x:%b-%Y}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0;font-size:11px;">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:,.0f}</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

use html in tooltip and format using dateFormat

```
Highcharts.dateFormat(%Y-%m,this.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the tooltip header format

```
tooltip: {    
    xDateFormat: '%b %Y'
}
```

Or if you want to modify the whole html

```
tooltip: {    
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.key:%b \'%y}</b><br>'
}
```